# Set barplot color and add x-axis values

Tags: r

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/R

c1 <-c(60,199,102,134,81,95,135,151,102,112,211,120)
barplot(c1, main="number of points per cluster", 
    color="dark blue")
```

But warning message says

> Warning messages: 1: In plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) :
>   "color" is not a graphical parameter

My image[image]

I would also like to but numbers from 1 to 12 on x-axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the colour use `col`, not `color`. To have numbers on x-axis we can assign names the `c1`.

```
c1 <- c(60,199,102,134,81,95,135,151,102,112,211,120)
names(c1) <- 1:length(c1)

barplot(c1, main = "number of points per cluster", 
        col = "dark blue")
```

[image]

Comment: all whitespace is stripped in color names you just blew my mind

Comment: @rawr heh, actually you blew my mind, I didn't check if there were any colour names with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the other answer: You can also even go a step further for categorical data and match the colors to the data itself.

```
c1 = c(60,199,102,134,81,95,135,151,102,112,211,120)
names(c1) = LETTERS[1:length(c1)]  # random data labels from alphabet
barplot(sort(c1, decreasing=T),
        main="Barplot with Data-Based Colors",
        col=heat.colors(length(c1)))
```

[image]